# Question on the hypothesis of the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus

### [image][image]Question:

Find all numbers c from g(x) = 3x/(x + 7) on the interval [-1,2] such that it satisfies the hypothesis of the mean value theorem.

---

### My problem/answer:

Mean value theorem states that g must be continuous and differentiable, which is true in this case. MVT also states that at some point c, the tangent line at some point c is equal to the secant line of the end points.

However for the answer I got which is c = 3(√6)-7, when I graph the original function and its derivative on the graph and also graph this point c, the slopes aren't parallel to each other. Is this some error from my calculation or am I not seeing something?

### The two slopes are the opposite, one is positive and one is negative. If you graph 3x/(x + 7) and 21/(x+7)^2 and x = 3(√6)-7, you will see that the slopes aren't parallel at that point.

So is the answer c = 3(√6)-7 still correct? The two slopes are supposed to be parallel to each other at this point c but are not, even though my calculations are correct.

Answer (score 2):

With $\;g(x)=\cfrac{3x}{x+7}=3\left(1-\cfrac7{x+7}\right)\;$ on $\;[-1,2]\;$ , we get:

$$\frac{g(2)-g(-1)}{2-(-1)}=\frac{\frac6{9}-\frac{-3}{6}}3=\frac{\frac23+\frac12}{3}=\frac7{18}$$

whereas

$$g'(x)=\frac{21}{(x+7)^2}\stackrel ?=\frac7{18}\implies(x+7)^2=54\implies x=\pm3\sqrt6-7$$

So now check there's only one value possible...and it is the one you got!

Comment: Yes, that is the same as my answer but I am asking how this value for x is possible when the slopes don't look parallel to each other when you graph it out

Comment: @harold232 What **slopes** are you talking about? There's only one function: $\;g(x)\;$ ! Ok, now I see the red line is the derivative's function..and they both indeed meet at some point between $\;-1\;$ and $\;2\;$ , so what is the problem?

Comment: @harold232 You seem to be lieve $\;g,\,g'\;$ must have tangent lines with the same slope: that isn't necessarily true. The **chord** obtained by $\;\frac{g(2)-g(-1)}{2-(-1)}\;$ has the same slope that $g\;$ at some point, meaning: that slope equals $\;g'(x)\;$ for some point in the interval....and you and other have just proved!

Comment: the red line is actually the original function and the blue is the derivative of that function. The slopes aren't parallel to each other at this point so how is this valid?

Comment: Because the MVT doesn't say the slope of those lines must be parallel at two points! Please read the rest of my comments.

Comment: No I said that MVT states there exists no more that one point where the tangent slope of that point is equal to the secant line of the two end points

Comment: The secant is what I call chord. Where and who say the MVT says there's no more than one such point? There can be many, in fact/

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think the slopes of $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$ must be equal?
Slope of $g(x)$ at $x=c$ equals the *value*  $g'(c)$. Not the slope of $g'(c)$

Take a look at the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uaq07dv0gs) showing the function $g(x)$, secant line, and the tangent line parallel to the secant line.
[image]

Comment: No I said that the MVT states that if g is cont and diff, then there is a point where the slope of tangent line is parallel/the same as the secant line between the two end points

Comment: Yes that is what I said

Comment: Then you're right. But in your graph you didn't draw the secant line between the two endpoints. You just plotted $g(x)$ and $g'(x)$. I'm wondering why you're even looking at the slope of $g'(x)$

Comment: @harold232 Again, that that you said is *wrong*: the chord between two points (the interval's extreme points) on the graph of $\;g\;$ has a slope equal to $\;g'(x)\;$: **that is true!**

Comment: Yes this is what I just said. To better understand what I'm asking consider the interval [-1,1], where you are told to find the point where y=x^3 satisfies the MVT. The point would be √(1/3), and this makes sense because when you graph it out, you can tell the slopes are parallel to each other

Comment: Ok. For y=x^3, which two slopes are parallel to each other?

Comment: the tangent slope at c =  √(1/3) and the secant slope of (-1,1), check my new posted picture to understand my idea of the MVT

Comment: Ok we're good with x^3. Did you draw the secant line between endpoints for your graph g(x) ?

Comment: I'm asking because I don't see a secant line between endpoints in your graph. So honestly I still don't know which two slopes you're talking about.

Comment: What does the green line of your graph represent

Comment: It is the secant line connecting the end points on the graph of $g(x)$ between $x=-1$ and  $x=2$

Comment: Oh I understand now, MVT is basically saying that there is at least one point on the original function where the tangent line on that point of the original function is equal to the secant line of the two end points of that original function. I was confused because I thought it meant the tangent line of the derivative function

Comment: Been there haha! I see you nailed it:) I like this speed analogy: Slope of secant line represents `average velocity`. And since the slope of tangent line represents `instantaneous velocity`, MVT is basically saying that `average speed = instantenous speed` for some point in the interval.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the (only) answer is $3\sqrt6-7$ indeed. And there must be some error in your computations, since both slopes are equal to $\frac7{18}$; see the graph below.

[image]

Comment: But from the graph I posted you can see that the slopes are not parallel to each other or in other words don't have the slope of 7/18

Comment: If that is the correct answer for c, then there is no error in my calculation. I am confused because both slopes at this point should be the same, but when graphed out, the slopes look different

Comment: @harold232 In your graph, the red curve is the function. What is the blue one??

Comment: red is g(x) and blue is g'(x)

Comment: There are only two slopes here: the slope of the line defined by $(-1,g(-1))$ and $(2,g(2))$ and the slope of the line tangent to the graph at $(c,g(c))$. And they are equal.

Comment: Yes that is correct, but how are they equal. From my graph, you can tell that one slope is increasing and the other is decreasing

Comment: I've added a graph to my answer. What do you think now?